# Best data structure/algorithm to find best matches between two lists with multiple possible matches

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, matching

I have two lists of elements of different lenghts (N != M),

```
A = [a_0, a_1, ..., a_N]
B = [b_0, b_1, ..., b_M]
```

The elements in the lists are numeric intervals, and I have to find the best matches between them based on a given metric (basically, the Intersection over Union of these intervals).

According to this, I used a simple nested for loop to compare all the elements of the two lists between each other:

```
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        found_match_score(a, b)
```

This way, I found the possible elements from B matching the elements from A, and I arranged the results in a dict...for each element from A, I have a dictionary showing the possible matches from B, and the corresponding matching score:

```
{
a_0: {},
a_1: {b_0: 0.25},
a_2: {b_0: 0.5},
a_3: {},
a_4: {b_1: 0.29},
a_5: {b_1: 0.33},
a_6: {b_2: 0.25},
a_7: {b_2: 0.57},
a_8: {b_4: 0.10,
      b_5: 0.25},
a_9: {b_5: 0.44},
a_10: {b_6: 0.17,
       b_7: 0.25}
a_11: {b_7: 0.3,
       b_8: 0.43}
}
```

Now, I need to go over this structure and find the best matches, so that ideally I end up with this result (I want each matching to be unique):

```
{
a_0: {},
a_1: {},
a_2: {b_0: 0.5},
a_3: {},
a_4: {},
a_5: {b_1: 0.33},
a_6: {},
a_7: {b_2: 0.57},
a_8: {b_4: 0.10},
a_9: {b_5: 0.44},
a_10: {b_7: 0.25}
a_11: {b_8: 0.43}
}
```

I could do this by iterating over the dictionary, checking if some B elements match multiple items from A, store them to a temp object, and only keep the best matching one, until I get the results.
But this seems kinda convoluted, and I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it. Maybe I'm using the wrong data structure altogether?

Comment: It's unclear what your algorithm should do and i wonder if it would be not more important to improve the algorithm instead of improving data-structures of a sub-optimal algorithm? So when there are multiple choices, which one do you select? It seems if you select one, it's blocked in others where this match could appear? Doing that optimally seems not that easy (if one does not recognize a well-researched problem). Your approach looks like a *greedy-algorithm* without any optimality guarantees? Is that your focus and you want to speed up? If not... this looks like *min-cost network-flow* prob.

Comment: In many interpretations of the task at hand, the task becomes much more easier rendering it an rectangular linear-assignment problem (basically special-case of min-cost network-flows).

Comment: I am not sure the upper algorithm will work anytime. Two or more elements from B can match equally to one element in A, and if you choose wrong one here, all further elements could find incorrect match in A.